# WIndows Phone 7 : Image does not rotate in landscape mode

Tags: windows-phone-7, rotation, image-rotation, landscape-portrait

I am overriding the `OnOrientationChanged` as below

```
 protected override void OnOrientationChanged(OrientationChangedEventArgs e)  
 {  
     Grid.SetRow(hyperlinkButton1, 0);
     Grid.SetRow(hyperlinkButton2, 1);
 }
```

Now with this I am able to put grid vertically stacked in portrait mode. And horizontally stacked in vertical mode.

But the child inside are not rotating. In landscape mode they are not see upright but aligned to portrait mode.

How do I rotate individual child[Image, grid etc] to make them upright in landscape mode also.

Comment: Do you have a full repro? The child controls should rotate, unless you're using a popup (which has some issue with supporting orientation changes correctly).

Answer (score 3):

If you want to rotate only SPECIFIC controls on a page when the orientation is changed - this cannot be done automatically. You can only put a RotateTransform in XAML and bind to it. This RotateTransform can then be modified by the code when the orientation is changed.

If, on the other hand you're talking about rotating the entire page then you need to add SupportedOrientations=”PortraitOrLandscape” to the page element.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Change SupportedOrientations=”PortraitOrLandscape” on your xaml page.